# Pythonon ajax php prase result is different from on screen result?

Tags: php, python, ajax, mismatch

I tried to extract a search result from this page: "http://std.stheadline.com/daily/formerly.php".
While selecting on webpage 20-Nov to 22-Nov and checking  the "財經" news category check box, gives 47 results.
However, my python php codes with parameters obtained from Chrome Inspect, yield 162 results. It seems the sever did not recognize my code parameters and given me the results of ALL news categories of the latest date.

I used this codes:
import pandas as pd

```
url=  "http://std.stheadline.com/daily/ajax/ajaxFormerly.php?startDate=2019-11-20&endDate=2019-11-22&type%5B%5D=15&keyword="

df = pd.read_json(url)
print(df.info(verbose=True))
print(df)
```

also tried:

```
url=  "http://std.stheadline.com/daily/ajax/ajaxFormerly.php?startDate=2019-11-20&endDate=2019-11-22&type=15&keyword="
```

Comment: in Firefox I see it uses `POST` request and sends parameters in body, not in url. You may have to use module `urllib` or `requests` to send `POST` request and get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses `POST` request which sends parameters in body, not in url. You can't send parameters in url. You may use module `requests` (or `urllib`) to send `POST` requests

```
import requests

url = 'http://std.stheadline.com/daily/ajax/ajaxFormerly.php'

params = {
    'startDate': '2019-11-20',
    'endDate': '2019-11-22',
    'type[]': '15',
    'keyword': '',
}

r = requests.post(url, data=params)

data = r.json()

print(data['totalCount']) # 47
```

To load it to `DataFrame` you may have to use `io.StringIO` to create file in memory.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

url = 'http://std.stheadline.com/daily/ajax/ajaxFormerly.php'

params = {
    'startDate': '2019-11-20',
    'endDate': '2019-11-22',
    'type[]': '15',
    'keyword': '',
}

r = requests.post(url, data=params)

f = io.StringIO(r.text)
df = pd.read_json(f)

print(df)
```